# How to read/print the contents for excel file using docx4j?

Tags: java, excel, docx4j

I've been googling and I've not found one example for this.

I am able to extract the contents for a DOCX file but so far no clue how to get the contents of an EXCEL file.

I know you use

```
SpreadsheetMLPackage spreadsheetMLPackage = SpreadsheetMLPackage.load(file);
```

to load the file, but I don't know how to proceed from here. I've check whatever methods SpreadsheetMLPackage has but nothing has gotten me the contents.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand the structure of a xlsx file.

Unzip one, or run it through the [docx4j webapp](http://webapp.docx4java.org).

For how the parts relate to one another, see:

http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2007/08/13/1970.aspx

I guess the key method you'll want is [getWorksheet](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/ba59b54f7cfbaaeee7463e6052132ca4c76f423e)

But first you'll need to get the WorkbookPart; do that with spreadsheetMLPackage.getWorkbookPart()